# c++ friend overloading operator <<

Tags: c++, overloading, friend

I am trying overload the operator << but i keep having this error. I try doing research but with no result. I have a Point2D.h and a Point2D.cpp with a friend functions to overload. Below are my codes:

Point2D.h

```
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

#ifndef Point2D_H
#define Point2D_H

class Point2D
{
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, Point2D);

    public:

        Point2D();

        Point2D(int, int);

    protected:

        int x;
        int y;
};
```

Point.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Point2D.h"

Point2D::Point2D() {
    this->x=0;
    this->y=0;
}

Point2D::Point2D(int x, int y) {
    this->x=x;
    this->y=y;
}
ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, Point2D pt)
{
    out << "Point = " <<pt.x;
    return out;
}
#endif
```

Below are my error message, not sure why there is no match for that method

```
Point2D.h: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Point2D)’:
Point2D.h:37:9: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘int’)
     out << pt.x;
         ^
Point2D.h:37:9: note: candidates are:
Point2D.h:35:10: note: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Point2D)
 ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, Point2D pt)
          ^
Point2D.h:35:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘int’ to ‘Point2D’
In file included from Point2D.h:2:0,
                 from Point3D.h:2,
                 from Point3D.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/iomanip:235:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::_Setw)
 operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os, _Setw __f)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
#include <iostream>
```

Or at least

```
#include <ostream>
```

---

2 other advises:

- the include guards (`ifndef`, `define` and `endif`) should be at the very beginning and at the very end of the *header* file (the `endif` MUST NOT be in the source file, but in the header file)
- Adding `using namespace std;` in headers is bad practice. Use `std::` prefix at least in the header. It's your choice if you'll use `using namespace std;` in the source. I wouldn't, but it's my personal choice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include another header

```
#include <iostream>
```

Only `#include <ostream>` will suffice though.

Answer (score 0):

Correct code (see comments in code):

Point2D.h:

```
#include <string>
// #include <iomanip> // this includes io manipulators you do not need here
#include <iosfwd> // minimalist forward declarations for io streams

// using namespace std; // don't do this :(

#ifndef Point2D_H // should be above the includes
#define Point2D_H // should be above the includes

class Point2D
{
    // friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, Point2D);
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const Point2D &);
    // observe pass by const reference
```

Point2D.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
// #include <iomanip> // not needed
#include <iostream> // std::ostream class definition
#include "Point2D.h"

Point2D::Point2D() {
    this->x=0;
    this->y=0;
}

Point2D::Point2D(int x, int y) {
    this->x=x;
    this->y=y;
}
// ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, Point2D pt)
std::ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, const Point2D& pt)
{
    out << "Point = " << pt.x;
    return out;
}
// #endif // this shouldn't be here
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all move directive

```
#endif
```

from the file `Point.cpp` to the end of the file `Point2D.h`
The files will look like

Point2D.h

```
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

#ifndef Point2D_H
#define Point2D_H

//...

#endif
```

Point.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Point2D.h"

Point2D::Point2D() {
    this->x=0;
    this->y=0;
}

Point2D::Point2D(int x, int y) {
    this->x=x;
    this->y=y;
}
ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, Point2D pt)
{
    out << "Point = " <<pt.x;
    return out;
}
//    #endif - removed
```

And substitute

```
#include <iomanip>
```

for

```
#include <iostream>
```

or at least add header

```
#include <iostream>
```

to the module file where the operator is defined.

Also the operator should be declared like

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, const Point2D &pt);
```

Otherwise each time when the operator will be used a temporary object of type Point2D will be created.