# After adding cout as friend operator, c++ still shows error 1)cout is ambiguous . Why?

Tags: c++, overloading, constants, cout, friend

Cout is shown to be ambiguous even after adding cout as a friend operator. Attached is a part of my code that I though may help in understand what is the problem. IDE is visual studio.

I tried adding friend << into class called stack and in some stack functions like push, I need to cout messages in string e.g."stack overflow". However, cout here is shown to be an error even after adding cout as friend. I don't know what went wrong, can anybody help? Really appreciate it.

```
{


friend ostream &operator << (ostream &outs, const string &y);
};

ostream &operator << (ostream &outs, const string &y) {
outs << y;
return outs;

}
bool Stack::push(int x)
{
if (top >= (2 - 1)) {
    cout << "Stack Overflow";
    return false;
}
```

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: I see, correct the problem, hope it's better for viewing now. it is only part of the code that I thought was related to the cout problem

Comment: Ask yourself, what is the function return type and what am I returning?

Comment: "shown to be an error" doesn't help as much as showing us the *exact error text* so please edit and include that as well. I think anastaciu has identified the problem, but it'd be nice to confirm that.

Comment: Why do you even want a custom `operator<<` overload? `cout << "abc";` should work as is.

Comment: Um, I should be returning a string and the return type should be string? The exact error is "cout" is ambiguous and 'return':cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'std::ostream&' for this line 'return y';

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes but when I did that originally, cout is ambiguous error is already there so I thought cout may have another overloaded use? I'm not sure

Comment: Post the error in the question , the error explains itself, you should be returning `ostream&` yet you are returning `string`.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Printing strings should work without any custom `operator<<`. If it doesn't for you, can you make us a [mcve] (without any attempted fixes).

Comment: Im not sure if this is what you mean but I changed return y to return outs. But the error is still there.

Comment: okay I'll try doing that @HolyBlackCat

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, that is the correct return, the error should have been fixed, post the exact error messages in the question.

Comment: Unrelated - if you define the overload like you do, there is no purpose in declaring it friend or declaring it at all inside the class.

Comment: I tried producing a minimal reproducible example but the error shown in question started when I first input cout without class stack or overloading cout. So I'm not sure what I can still cut away from my code post above...I'm sorry. Is there anything else I can do to deal with this? @HolyBlackCat

Comment: I now added the exact error in the question @anastaciu

Comment: I don't see it, post the error inside the question, copy/paste it, anyway it should work fine as you can see here https://wandbox.org/permlink/rhRCcJhOMP6czSrX maybe there is something you're not showing that's causing the error.

Comment: Okay thanks! I will try to look at it again from what you provided! @anastaciu

Comment: Please upload the code somewhere and provide a link somewhere. That would help a lot in providing answers.

Comment: This might help:
[c++ friend overloading operator <<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392277/c-friend-overloading-operator?)